# ¿Cómo pasarle todas los días del mes al encabezado de un pivot en sql?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

He creado una consulta en sql server con pivot para que invierta las filas en columnas.

Lo que deseo es que en vez de pasarle las cabeceras de fechas de manera estática, hacerlo de manera dinámica mediante una función, quizás un procedimiento almacenado que al pasarle un mes y un año me imprima los días del mes de acuerdo al parámetro recibido, líneas debajo les dejo mi consulta realizada en sql server.

```
SELECT * FROM
(select 
Id_Colaborador,
Nombre_Colaborador,
Id_Unidad_Organizativa,
Fecha_Registro,
sum(Hora_Registro) as 'Hora_Registro'
from Sigeri
group by Id_Colaborador,Nombre_Colaborador,Id_Unidad_Organizativa,Fecha_Registro
)s
pivot(
    max(Hora_Registro)
    for[Fecha_Registro] in ([2019-08-01],
[2019-08-02],
[2019-08-05],
[2019-08-06],
[2019-08-07],
[2019-08-08],
[2019-08-09],
[2019-08-12],
[2019-08-13],
[2019-08-14],
[2019-08-15],
[2019-08-16],
[2019-08-19],
[2019-08-20],
[2019-08-21],
[2019-08-22],
[2019-08-23],
[2019-08-26],
[2019-08-27],
[2019-08-28],
[2019-08-29])
)p
```

Comment: En esta pregunta deseo hacer una función que me imprima los días de un determinado mes y año pasado como parametro

Comment: Es el mismo problema de la otra pregunta. Sólo que no fue solucionada de manera completa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo te muestro un ejemplo y ya te lo vuelves función o lo que necesites.

Esta QUERY recibe el mes y año como string y siempre empieza en día 1.

```
Declare @Mes VARCHAR(2)='10' --Mes
Declare @Año VARCHAR(5)='2019'--AÑO
DECLARE @SQLDynamic NVARCHAR(MAX)-- STRING QUE CONTENDRA TODO
DECLARE @FinalDate NVARCHAR(50)=@Año+'-'+@Mes+'-01'-- creamos el año + el mes + el primer dia

--obtiene el primer dia del mes
;WITH CTE_DAY_Recursive AS
(
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @FinalDate), 0)  AS date)AS DayDINAMIC --Creamos el promer dia
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DayDINAMIC)--agregamos un dia mas
FROM CTE_DAY_Recursive
Where DATEADD(DAY,1,DayDINAMIC)<=CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@FinalDate)+1,0)-1 AS DATE)--verificamos que no se pase de la fecha del mes
)
SELECT  @SQLDynamic=COALESCE(@SQLDynamic+',','')+'['+CAST(DayDINAMIC    AS nvarchar(20))+']' 
FROM CTE_DAY_Recursive  --Obtenemos los registros 

DECLARE @SQLFULL NVARCHAR(MAX)='

select * from
(
select 
Id_Colaborador,
Nombre_Colaborador,
Id_Unidad_Organizativa,
Fecha_Registro,
Hora_Registro
from Sigeri
)s
pivot(
    max(Hora_Registro)
    for[Fecha_Registro] in --(select Fecha_Registro FROM Sigeri)
('+@SQLDynamic+') --Le pasamos los registros
)p'


EXEC(@SQLFULL)
```

Al final regresa todos los días del mes que le diste.

Demostración.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38e7cf571fccf2cbccfc87283ea7a2b0

Comment: Estimado la resolución es buena pero no detecta si el mes tiene 30 o 31 días y además de ello me gustaría que se imprimiera con el formato mostrado en mi código de ejemplo con comas y corchetes ya que el pivot es bien estricto con el formato que se le pasa y tampoco varia el mes pasado.

Comment: el problema era el orden de la fecha mes y día los cambie de lugar funciono bien.

Comment: Ya esta en ese formato amigo +'['+CAST(DayDINAMIC    AS nvarchar(20))+']' en esa linea se hace

Comment: Estimado Edgar Vazquez y como podría ser para un rango de fechas en vez de un mes completo agradecería me pudieras ayudar.

Comment: Como que un rango de fechas esas tu las tienes o como?

Comment: ya lo solucione gracias.